# How to get browsed filepath in jsp..............?

Tags: java, file-upload

Hi
   i am selecting a txt/XLS file through  and need to pass the same to a function to read the content and its not happening for me ....... how can i pass file path to file content reader Function

Code am using to Browse file:

```
    <input type="file" name="uploadfile" id="uploadfile" size="40" value=""/>

BufferedReader bF =  new BufferedReader(new FileReader(*** File Path here ***));

BufferedReader bF =  new BufferedReader(new FileReader("cia.txt"));
```

I want to get dynamic selected files into file reader......

Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If variable `"uploadfile"`  is an File type variable(need to be) then try `uploadfile.getAbsolutePath()`

Btw what server side technology you are using(framework)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something like [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/) to process uploaded files.